# Find highest value in column insert a new record 1 number higher in said column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a single MySQL insert query that will identify the highest value in a column and then increment it by one for the record being inserted. I thought when I made the table that I had this field set to auto_increment but it does not work for some reason. My current insert statement is:

```sql
INSERT INTO victoria (name, album, order_by) VALUES (:name, :album, :order)
```

The order_by field is the one that needs to increment by one.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to fix the problem with your auto increment field.

Comment: Please post the table schema as a result of issuing `DESC victoria`

Comment: If you put auto increment in `order_by` field, you should not include that field in the insert statement. So your insert statement should be: `INSERT INTO victoria (name, album) VALUES (:name, :album)`

Comment: I am going to just fix the problem of the auto_increment by rebuilding the database its only 50 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, for some reason, to increment a value of a column without using an `auto_increment` column you can do something like this

```sql
INSERT INTO victoria 
SELECT :name, :album, 
       COALESCE((SELECT MAX(order_by) FROM victoria), 0) + 1;
```

*Note: it might fail to provide you with a distinct value under heavy load, meaning several concurrent users inserting rows at the same time can grab the same `MAX(order_by)` value. Therefore if you are not planning to "reorder" rows latter you better stick with an `auto_increment` column.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f3c9/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks I am just going to end up rebuilding it and fixing it right since the order needs to always stay accurate